# Cloudtrail not logging my s3 bucket events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I created a trail with data events:
[image: Data Events in cloudtrail]

But when I go into the management console and upload a file to any s3 bucket, i cannot see the PutObject Event anywhere in cloudtrail:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-cloudtrail-logging-for-s3.html):

> CloudTrail does not populate data events in the CloudTrail event history. Additionally, not all bucket-level actions are populated in the CloudTrail event history.

If you create a CloudTrail Trail manually, the management and data events recorded by this Trail are delivered to an S3 bucket and to CloudWatch Logs (if enabled). There are several tools to query S3 bucket data/CloudWatch Logs if you want to see these events.

Nevertheless, you wont be able to see data events in Event History, even if you enable them on a Trail created by you.

Comment: is it possible to see the event, that uploaded a file to an S3 bucket?

Comment: When you create the trail, you specify a bucket. If you go into that bucket, you should be able to see a bunch of json files, created by the trail, which contain the data events (for example: file uploads to S3). Keep in mind, CloudTrail is not real-time, you will see events after a few seconds/minutes. As I said, you wont bee able to see these file upload events in the Event History.

Comment: @David You can use [Athena to query the logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html).